# Can constant key input move a sprite constantly?

Tags: python, sprite, pygame, game-engine

If I want to move a sprite based on key input in pygame, is there anyway to write code so if I hold down a key, the sprite will keep moving in that direction until I release the key? I've tried this and either the program crashes or I have to repeatedly tap the keys to move the sprite in the intended direction.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pygame, does it working using keyboard states?

Answer (score 5):

The OP wants keystate polling, not `KEYDOWN` events.

This example shows using both key events, and key polling. You use one for 'on key press' and the other for 'while held down'.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

done = False    
player.pos = Rect(0,0,10,10)

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # any other key event input
        if event.type == QUIT:
            done = True        
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESC:
                done = True

    # get key current state
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        player.pos.left -= 10
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        player.pos.left += 10
    if keys[K_UP]:
        player.pos.top -= 10
    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        player.pos.left += 10
    if keys[K_SPACE]: 
        print 'firing gun'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an overview,

- Listen for the `KEYDOWN` event in the pygame message queue.
- Check if the key you're interested in is pushed down.
- Move in that direction
- Check message queue for `KEYUP` event that matches your key.
- Stop moving.

Read the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/) as to how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You normally use have a moving function in your update method that looks like this:

```
this.pos_x = direction * speed * delta
```

Now on your KEYDOWN events you set your direction to 1 or -1 and on KEYUP you set it back to 0. That way you have a nice constant movement.