# Difficulty with movement in game close to Pong (pygame)

Tags: pygame

Note: I am really new in programming.

At first, I am just going to post the code I have written:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480])
paddle = pygame.image.load("pulgake.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG!")
WHITE = [0, 0, 0]

back = pygame.image.load("taust.png")
screen.blit(back, (0, 0))
screen.blit(paddle, (600, 240))
pygame.display.flip()

xpaddle = 600
ypaddle = 240 

delay = 10
interval = 10
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos = [0,0]
        self.velocity = [1,0]

def move():
    self.pos[0] += self.velocity[0]
    self.pos[1] += self.velocity[1]
    if self.pos[0] > 10:
        self.pos[0] *= -1
    elif self.pos[1] > 470: # My background has a frame
        self.pos[1] *= -1
    elif self.pos[1] < 10:
        self.pos[1] *= -1
    elif self.pos[0] > 605:
        False

def draw(screen):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,self.pos,15)

pall = Ball() 

while True:
    pall.move()
    screen.blit(back, (0,0))
    screen.blit(paddle, (xpaddle, ypaddle))
    pygame.display.flip()
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif i.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if i.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ypaddle = ypaddle - 10
                if ypaddle < 10:
                    ypaddle = 10
            elif i.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ypaddle = ypaddle + 10
                if ypaddle > 410:
                    ypaddle = 410
```

I am getting this error-

```
line 44, in <module>
    pall.move()
TypeError: move() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

So, I want to get a ball that bounces off the walls (and paddle as well, but I don't know yet how)

Also, I would be really grateful if somebody helps me to get a stopwatch in this game, showing time "survived".

EDIT: added `def move(self)`
Now, a bigger problem occured:

draw() and move() - global name"self" not defined.
I really can't figure out  this one.

Comment: draw() and move() are not inside your Ball class so you cannot call pall.move() and this line in draw() pygame.draw.circle(screen,WHITE,self.pos,15)     is trying to use a global named self which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `ball.move` which doesn't exist, because `move` needs to be indented once more.

If you want "do stuff while key is held down" You can use `getkeystate` and use KEYDOWN events when you want 'do stuff once, when key is pressed'

see both here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207525/341744